# nginx: server_name and server_addr wrong with reverse proxy in front of it

Tags: nginx, http, reverse-proxy, stunnel

I have stunnel in front of nginx in order to handle ssl. (I'm aware that nginx can handle ssl, but I'm migrating off nginx and this is a necessary step.)

Stunnel and nginx are running on the same box.

Without stunnel in front of nginx, nginx got the server_addr and server_name as the public ip of the box and the domain of the url I was fetching, respectively.

Now with stunnel, nginx thinks the server_addr and server_name are 127.0.0.1 and localhost respectively. This is screwing up a bunch of things.

How can I make nginx get (or stunnel send) the correct server_addr and server_name?

Answer (score 1):

However, since Stunnel is a proxy an has no knowledge of HTTP, the client's IP address was lost, which is somewhat annoying.

Try ngx_http_realip_module and [`X-Forwarded-For` support for Stunnel](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/#down):

```
set_real_ip_from   192.168.2.1;
real_ip_header     X-Forwarded-For;
```